# Where should I ask questions about determining hosting requirements?

Tags: discussion

Hello,

Is Pro Webmasters the right place to ask advice about how to go about determining hosting requirements for my project? If it isn't, what stackexchange site do you reckon is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the right place to ask.

Comment: Thanks very much!